# Google reverse geocoding, get City/Country from latlng

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Currently I am making an API request to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY&latlng=48.866667,2.333333` where the **latlng** is the geo-point of Paris,France. What filters exactly do I have to pass in the request to get the Paris/France (city/country) as response for the specified latitude and longitude?

Thank you in advance colleagues!

Answer (score 2):

Google is a bit of an overkill if you only want country/city. 3geonames.org is faster and it is free api (no api key needed).

https://api.3geonames.org/48.866667,2.333333

```html
<geodata>
<nearest>
<latt>48.86586</latt>
<longt>2.33423</longt>
<elevation>48</elevation>
<timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
<city>Paris</city>
<name>Paris 02 Ancien - Quartier Palais-Royal</name>
<prov>Île-de-France</prov>
<region>Paris</region>
<state>FR</state>
<inlatt>48.866667</inlatt>
<inlongt>2.333333</inlongt>
<altgeocode>PARISBUTTE-AZLQK</altgeocode>
<distance>0.111</distance>
</nearest>
<osmtags>
<wikipedia>fr:Quartier du Palais-Royal</wikipedia>
<wikidata>Q1763626</wikidata>
<source>www.mairie1.paris.fr</source>
<short_name>Palais Royal</short_name>
<name>Quartier du Palais Royal</name>
<admin_level>10</admin_level>
<addr_postcode>75001</addr_postcode>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<ref_INSEE>7510103</ref_INSEE>
<type>boundary</type>
<state>FR</state>
<id>266124</id>
</osmtags>
<adminareas>
<admin6>
<osmid>265283</osmid>
<level>6</level>
<ISO3166_2>FR-75</ISO3166_2>
<admin_level>6</admin_level>
<alt_name_fr>Lutèce</alt_name_fr>
<alt_name_vi>Ba Lê</alt_name_vi>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<loc_name_fr>Panam</loc_name_fr>
<name_af>Parys</name_af>
<name_am>ፓሪስ</name_am>
<name_an>París</name_an>
<name_ar>باريس</name_ar>
<name_arc>ܦܐܪܝܣ</name_arc>
<name_arz>باريس</name_arz>
<name_ast>París</name_ast>
<name_ba>Париж</name_ba>
<name_bat_smg>Parīžios</name_bat_smg>
<name_be_tarask>Парыж</name_be_tarask>
<name_be>Парыж</name_be>
<name_bg>Париж</name_bg>
<name_bn>প্যারিস</name_bn>
<name_bo>ཕ་རི།</name_bo>
<name_br>Pariz</name_br>
<name_bs>Pariz</name_bs>
<name_ca>París</name_ca>
<name_cdo>Bă-là̤</name_cdo>
<name_ckb>پاریس</name_ckb>
<name_co>Parighji</name_co>
<name_cs>Paříž</name_cs>
<name_csb>Pariz</name_csb>
<name_cu>Парижь</name_cu>
<name_cv>Парис</name_cv>
<name_de>Paris</name_de>
<name_el>Παρίσι</name_el>
<name_eml>Parì</name_eml>
<name_eo>Parizo</name_eo>
<name_es>París</name_es>
<name_et>Pariis</name_et>
<name_eu>Paris</name_eu>
<name_ext>París</name_ext>
<name_fa>پاریس</name_fa>
<name_fi>Pariisi</name_fi>
<name_fiu_vro>Pariis</name_fiu_vro>
<name_fr>Paris</name_fr>
<name_fur>Parîs</name_fur>
<name_fy>Parys</name_fy>
<name_ga>Páras</name_ga>
<name_gan>巴黎</name_gan>
<name_gl>París</name_gl>
<name_gn>Parĩ</name_gn>
<name_gu>પૅરિસ</name_gu>
<name_gv>Paarys</name_gv>
<name_ha>Pariis</name_ha>
<name_hak>Pâ-lì-sṳ</name_hak>
<name_haw>Palika</name_haw>
<name_he>פריז</name_he>
<name_hi>पैरिस</name_hi>
<name_hr>Pariz</name_hr>
<name_ht>Pari</name_ht>
<name_hu>Párizs</name_hu>
<name_hy>Փարիզ</name_hy>
<name_is>París</name_is>
<name_it>Parigi</name_it>
<name_ja>パリ</name_ja>
<name_jbo>Paris</name_jbo>
<name_ka>პარიზი</name_ka>
<name_kk>Париж</name_kk>
<name_km>ប៉ារីស</name_km>
<name_kn>ಪ್ಯಾರಿಸ್</name_kn>
<name_ko>파리</name_ko>
<name_koi>Париж</name_koi>
<name_krc>Париж</name_krc>
<name_ku>Parîs</name_ku>
<name_kv>Париж</name_kv>
<name_ky>Париж</name_ky>
<name_la>Lutetia</name_la>
<name_lb>Paräis</name_lb>
<name_lez>Париж</name_lez>
<name_li>Paries</name_li>
<name_lij>Pariggi</name_lij>
<name_ln>Pari</name_ln>
<name_lt>Paryžius</name_lt>
<name_lv>Parīze</name_lv>
<name_lzh>巴黎</name_lzh>
<name_mhr>Париж</name_mhr>
<name_mi>Parī</name_mi>
<name_mk>Париз</name_mk>
<name_ml>പാരിസ്</name_ml>
<name_mn>Парис</name_mn>
<name_mr>पॅरिस</name_mr>
<name_mrj>Париж</name_mrj>
<name_my>ပါရီမြို့</name_my>
<name_myv>Париж ош</name_myv>
<name_mzn>پاریس</name_mzn>
<name_nan>Pa-lí</name_nan>
<name_nap>Parigge</name_nap>
<name_nds_nl>Paries</name_nds_nl>
<name_nds>Paris</name_nds>
<name_ne>पेरिस</name_ne>
<name_nl>Parijs</name_nl>
<name_no>Paris</name_no>
<name_oc>París</name_oc>
<name_or>ପ୍ୟାରିସ</name_or>
<name_os>Париж</name_os>
<name_pa>ਪੈਰਿਸ</name_pa>
<name_pl>Paryż</name_pl>
<name_pnb>پیرس</name_pnb>
<name_ps>پاريس</name_ps>
<name_roa_rup>Parij</name_roa_rup>
<name_roa_tara>Parigge</name_roa_tara>
<name_ru>Париж</name_ru>
<name_rue>Паріж</name_rue>
<name_sah>Париж</name_sah>
<name_sc>Parigi</name_sc>
<name_scn>Pariggi</name_scn>
<name_sh>Pariz</name_sh>
<name_sk>Paríž</name_sk>
<name_sl>Pariz</name_sl>
<name_so>Baariis</name_so>
<name_sq>Parisi</name_sq>
<name_sr>Париз</name_sr>
<name_sv>Paris</name_sv>
<name_szl>Paryż</name_szl>
<name_ta>பாரிஸ்</name_ta>
<name_te>పారిస్</name_te>
<name_tet>París</name_tet>
<name_tg>Париж</name_tg>
<name_th>ปารีส</name_th>
<name_tk>Pariž</name_tk>
<name_tl>Paris</name_tl>
<name_tt>Париж</name_tt>
<name_tzl>Parighi</name_tzl>
<name_udm>Париж</name_udm>
<name_ug>پارىژ</name_ug>
<name_uk>Париж</name_uk>
<name_ur>پیرس</name_ur>
<name_uz>Parij</name_uz>
<name_vec>Parixe</name_vec>
<name_vep>Pariž</name_vep>
<name_vi>Paris</name_vi>
<name_vls>Parys</name_vls>
<name_wo>Pari</name_wo>
<name_xmf>პარიზი</name_xmf>
<name_yi>פאריז</name_yi>
<name_yo>Parisi</name_yo>
<name_yue>巴黎</name_yue>
<name_za>Bahliz</name_za>
<name_zh>巴黎</name_zh>
<name_zh_pinyin>Bālí</name_zh_pinyin>
<name_zu>IParisi</name_zu>
<name>Paris</name>
<old_name_vi>Ba Lê</old_name_vi>
<ref_INSEE>75</ref_INSEE>
<ref_NUTS>FR101</ref_NUTS>
<ref>75</ref>
<type>boundary</type>
<wikidata>Q90</wikidata>
<wikipedia>fr:Paris</wikipedia>
</admin6>
<admin7>
<osmid>266068</osmid>
<level>7</level>
<admin_level>7</admin_level>
<alt_name_fr>Lutèce</alt_name_fr>
<alt_name_vi>Ba Lê</alt_name_vi>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<loc_name_fr>Panam</loc_name_fr>
<name_af>Parys</name_af>
<name_am>ፓሪስ</name_am>
<name_an>París</name_an>
<name_ar>باريس</name_ar>
<name_arc>ܦܐܪܝܣ</name_arc>
<name_arz>باريس</name_arz>
<name_ast>París</name_ast>
<name_ba>Париж</name_ba>
<name_bat_smg>Parīžios</name_bat_smg>
<name_be_tarask>Парыж</name_be_tarask>
<name_be>Парыж</name_be>
<name_bg>Париж</name_bg>
<name_bn>প্যারিস</name_bn>
<name_bo>ཕ་རི།</name_bo>
<name_br>Pariz</name_br>
<name_bs>Pariz</name_bs>
<name_ca>París</name_ca>
<name_cdo>Bă-là̤</name_cdo>
<name_ckb>پاریس</name_ckb>
<name_co>Parighji</name_co>
<name_cs>Paříž</name_cs>
<name_csb>Pariz</name_csb>
<name_cu>Парижь</name_cu>
<name_cv>Парис</name_cv>
<name_de>Paris</name_de>
<name_el>Παρίσι</name_el>
<name_eml>Parì</name_eml>
<name_eo>Parizo</name_eo>
<name_es>París</name_es>
<name_et>Pariis</name_et>
<name_eu>Paris</name_eu>
<name_ext>París</name_ext>
<name_fa>پاریس</name_fa>
<name_fi>Pariisi</name_fi>
<name_fiu_vro>Pariis</name_fiu_vro>
<name_fr>Paris</name_fr>
<name_fur>Parîs</name_fur>
<name_fy>Parys</name_fy>
<name_ga>Páras</name_ga>
<name_gan>巴黎</name_gan>
<name_gl>París</name_gl>
<name_gn>Parĩ</name_gn>
<name_gu>પૅરિસ</name_gu>
<name_gv>Paarys</name_gv>
<name_ha>Pariis</name_ha>
<name_hak>Pâ-lì-sṳ</name_hak>
<name_haw>Palika</name_haw>
<name_he>פריז</name_he>
<name_hi>पैरिस</name_hi>
<name_hr>Pariz</name_hr>
<name_ht>Pari</name_ht>
<name_hu>Párizs</name_hu>
<name_hy>Փարիզ</name_hy>
<name_is>París</name_is>
<name_it>Parigi</name_it>
<name_ja>パリ</name_ja>
<name_jbo>Paris</name_jbo>
<name_ka>პარიზი</name_ka>
<name_kk>Париж</name_kk>
<name_km>ប៉ារីស</name_km>
<name_kn>ಪ್ಯಾರಿಸ್</name_kn>
<name_ko>파리</name_ko>
<name_koi>Париж</name_koi>
<name_krc>Париж</name_krc>
<name_ku>Parîs</name_ku>
<name_kv>Париж</name_kv>
<name_ky>Париж</name_ky>
<name_la>Lutetia</name_la>
<name_lb>Paräis</name_lb>
<name_lez>Париж</name_lez>
<name_li>Paries</name_li>
<name_lij>Pariggi</name_lij>
<name_ln>Pari</name_ln>
<name_lt>Paryžius</name_lt>
<name_lv>Parīze</name_lv>
<name_lzh>巴黎</name_lzh>
<name_mhr>Париж</name_mhr>
<name_mi>Parī</name_mi>
<name_mk>Париз</name_mk>
<name_ml>പാരിസ്</name_ml>
<name_mn>Парис</name_mn>
<name_mr>पॅरिस</name_mr>
<name_mrj>Париж</name_mrj>
<name_my>ပါရီမြို့</name_my>
<name_myv>Париж ош</name_myv>
<name_mzn>پاریس</name_mzn>
<name_nan>Pa-lí</name_nan>
<name_nap>Parigge</name_nap>
<name_nds_nl>Paries</name_nds_nl>
<name_nds>Paris</name_nds>
<name_ne>पेरिस</name_ne>
<name_nl>Parijs</name_nl>
<name_no>Paris</name_no>
<name_oc>París</name_oc>
<name_or>ପ୍ୟାରିସ</name_or>
<name_os>Париж</name_os>
<name_pa>ਪੈਰਿਸ</name_pa>
<name_pl>Paryż</name_pl>
<name_pnb>پیرس</name_pnb>
<name_ps>پاريس</name_ps>
<name_roa_rup>Parij</name_roa_rup>
<name_roa_tara>Parigge</name_roa_tara>
<name_ru>Париж</name_ru>
<name_rue>Паріж</name_rue>
<name_sah>Париж</name_sah>
<name_sc>Parigi</name_sc>
<name_scn>Pariggi</name_scn>
<name_sh>Pariz</name_sh>
<name_sk>Paríž</name_sk>
<name_sl>Pariz</name_sl>
<name_so>Baariis</name_so>
<name_sq>Parisi</name_sq>
<name_sr>Париз</name_sr>
<name_sv>Paris</name_sv>
<name_szl>Paryż</name_szl>
<name_ta>பாரிஸ்</name_ta>
<name_te>పారిస్</name_te>
<name_tet>París</name_tet>
<name_tg>Париж</name_tg>
<name_th>ปารีส</name_th>
<name_tk>Pariž</name_tk>
<name_tl>Paris</name_tl>
<name_tt>Париж</name_tt>
<name_tzl>Parighi</name_tzl>
<name_udm>Париж</name_udm>
<name_ug>پارىژ</name_ug>
<name_uk>Париж</name_uk>
<name_ur>پیرس</name_ur>
<name_uz>Parij</name_uz>
<name_vec>Parixe</name_vec>
<name_vep>Pariž</name_vep>
<name_vi>Paris</name_vi>
<name_vls>Parys</name_vls>
<name_wo>Pari</name_wo>
<name_xmf>პარიზი</name_xmf>
<name_yi>פאריז</name_yi>
<name_yo>Parisi</name_yo>
<name_yue>巴黎</name_yue>
<name_za>Bahliz</name_za>
<name_zh>巴黎</name_zh>
<name_zh_pinyin>Bālí</name_zh_pinyin>
<name_zu>IParisi</name_zu>
<name>Paris</name>
<old_name_vi>Ba Lê</old_name_vi>
<ref_INSEE>751</ref_INSEE>
<type>boundary</type>
<wikidata>Q2863958</wikidata>
<wikipedia>fr:Arrondissement de Paris</wikipedia>
</admin7>
<admin8>
<osmid>265176</osmid>
<level>8</level>
<addr_postcode>
75000;75001;75002;75003;75004;75005;75006;75007;75008;75009;75010;75011;75012;75013;75014;75015;75016;75017;75018;75019;75020;75116
</addr_postcode>
<admin_level>8</admin_level>
<alt_name_fr>Lutèce</alt_name_fr>
<alt_name_vi>Ba Lê</alt_name_vi>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<capital>yes</capital>
<is_in>Ile-de-France, France</is_in>
<loc_name_fr>Paname</loc_name_fr>
<name_af>Parys</name_af>
<name_am>ፓሪስ</name_am>
<name_an>París</name_an>
<name_ar>باريس</name_ar>
<name_arc>ܦܐܪܝܣ</name_arc>
<name_arz>باريس</name_arz>
<name_ast>París</name_ast>
<name_ba>Париж</name_ba>
<name_bat_smg>Parīžios</name_bat_smg>
<name_be_tarask>Парыж</name_be_tarask>
<name_be>Парыж</name_be>
<name_bg>Париж</name_bg>
<name_bn>প্যারিস</name_bn>
<name_bo>ཕ་རི།</name_bo>
<name_br>Pariz</name_br>
<name_bs>Pariz</name_bs>
<name_ca>París</name_ca>
<name_cdo>Bă-là̤</name_cdo>
<name_ckb>پاریس</name_ckb>
<name_co>Parighji</name_co>
<name_cs>Paříž</name_cs>
<name_csb>Pariz</name_csb>
<name_cu>Парижь</name_cu>
<name_cv>Парис</name_cv>
<name_de>Paris</name_de>
<name_el>Παρίσι</name_el>
<name_eml>Parì</name_eml>
<name_eo>Parizo</name_eo>
<name_es>París</name_es>
<name_et>Pariis</name_et>
<name_eu>Paris</name_eu>
<name_ext>París</name_ext>
<name_fa>پاریس</name_fa>
<name_fi>Pariisi</name_fi>
<name_fiu_vro>Pariis</name_fiu_vro>
<name_fr>Paris</name_fr>
<name_fur>Parîs</name_fur>
<name_fy>Parys</name_fy>
<name_ga>Páras</name_ga>
<name_gan>巴黎</name_gan>
<name_gl>París</name_gl>
<name_gn>Parĩ</name_gn>
<name_gu>પૅરિસ</name_gu>
<name_gv>Paarys</name_gv>
<name_ha>Pariis</name_ha>
<name_hak>Pâ-lì-sṳ</name_hak>
<name_haw>Palika</name_haw>
<name_he>פריז</name_he>
<name_hi>पैरिस</name_hi>
<name_hr>Pariz</name_hr>
<name_ht>Pari</name_ht>
<name_hu>Párizs</name_hu>
<name_hy>Փարիզ</name_hy>
<name_is>París</name_is>
<name_it>Parigi</name_it>
<name_ja>パリ</name_ja>
<name_jbo>paris</name_jbo>
<name_ka>პარიზი</name_ka>
<name_kk>Париж</name_kk>
<name_km>ប៉ារីស</name_km>
<name_kn>ಪ್ಯಾರಿಸ್</name_kn>
<name_ko>파리</name_ko>
<name_koi>Париж</name_koi>
<name_krc>Париж</name_krc>
<name_ku>Parîs</name_ku>
<name_kv>Париж</name_kv>
<name_ky>Париж</name_ky>
<name_la>Lutetia</name_la>
<name_lb>Paräis</name_lb>
<name_lez>Париж</name_lez>
<name_li>Paries</name_li>
<name_lij>Pariggi</name_lij>
<name_ln>Pari</name_ln>
<name_lt>Paryžius</name_lt>
<name_lv>Parīze</name_lv>
<name_lzh>巴黎</name_lzh>
<name_mhr>Париж</name_mhr>
<name_mi>Parī</name_mi>
<name_mk>Париз</name_mk>
<name_ml>പാരിസ്</name_ml>
<name_mn>Парис</name_mn>
<name_mr>पॅरिस</name_mr>
<name_mrj>Париж</name_mrj>
<name_my>ပါရီမြို့</name_my>
<name_myv>Париж ош</name_myv>
<name_mzn>پاریس</name_mzn>
<name_nan>Pa-lí</name_nan>
<name_nap>Parigge</name_nap>
<name_nds_nl>Paries</name_nds_nl>
<name_nds>Paris</name_nds>
<name_ne>पेरिस</name_ne>
<name_nl>Parijs</name_nl>
<name_no>Paris</name_no>
<name_oc>París</name_oc>
<name_or>ପ୍ୟାରିସ</name_or>
<name_os>Париж</name_os>
<name_pa>ਪੈਰਿਸ</name_pa>
<name_pl>Paryż</name_pl>
<name_pnb>پیرس</name_pnb>
<name_ps>پاريس</name_ps>
<name_roa_rup>Parij</name_roa_rup>
<name_roa_tara>Parigge</name_roa_tara>
<name_ru>Париж</name_ru>
<name_rue>Паріж</name_rue>
<name_sah>Париж</name_sah>
<name_sc>Parigi</name_sc>
<name_scn>Pariggi</name_scn>
<name_sh>Pariz</name_sh>
<name_sk>Paríž</name_sk>
<name_sl>Pariz</name_sl>
<name_so>Baariis</name_so>
<name_sq>Parisi</name_sq>
<name_sr>Париз</name_sr>
<name_sv>Paris</name_sv>
<name_szl>Paryż</name_szl>
<name_ta>பாரிஸ்</name_ta>
<name_te>పారిస్</name_te>
<name_tet>París</name_tet>
<name_tg>Париж</name_tg>
<name_th>ปารีส</name_th>
<name_tk>Pariž</name_tk>
<name_tl>Paris</name_tl>
<name_tt>Париж</name_tt>
<name_tzl>Parighi</name_tzl>
<name_udm>Париж</name_udm>
<name_ug>پارىژ</name_ug>
<name_uk>Париж</name_uk>
<name_ur>پیرس</name_ur>
<name_uz>Parij</name_uz>
<name_vec>Parixe</name_vec>
<name_vep>Pariž</name_vep>
<name_vi>Paris</name_vi>
<name_vls>Parys</name_vls>
<name_wo>Pari</name_wo>
<name_xmf>პარიზი</name_xmf>
<name_yi>פאריז</name_yi>
<name_yo>Parisi</name_yo>
<name_yue>巴黎</name_yue>
<name_za>Bahliz</name_za>
<name_zh>巴黎</name_zh>
<name_zh_pinyin>Bālí</name_zh_pinyin>
<name_zu>IParisi</name_zu>
<name>Paris</name>
<old_name_vi>Ba Lê</old_name_vi>
<population>2243833</population>
<ref_FR_MGP>T1</ref_FR_MGP>
<ref_INSEE>75056</ref_INSEE>
<source_population>INSEE 2013</source_population>
<type>boundary</type>
<wikidata>Q90</wikidata>
<wikipedia>fr:Paris</wikipedia>
</admin8>
<admin9>
<osmid>265195</osmid>
<level>9</level>
<addr_postcode>75001</addr_postcode>
<admin_level>9</admin_level>
<admin_type_FR>arrondissement municipal</admin_type_FR>
<alt_name>Ier Arrondissement</alt_name>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<landuse>residential</landuse>
<loc_name>Louvre</loc_name>
<name_en>1st Arrondissement</name_en>
<name_fr>Paris 1er Arrondissement</name_fr>
<name_ru>I округ</name_ru>
<name>Paris 1er Arrondissement</name>
<ref_INSEE>75101</ref_INSEE>
<short_name>1er</short_name>
<type>boundary</type>
<wikidata>Q161741</wikidata>
<wikipedia>fr:1er arrondissement de Paris</wikipedia>
</admin9>
<admin10>
<osmid>266124</osmid>
<level>10</level>
<addr_postcode>75001</addr_postcode>
<admin_level>10</admin_level>
<boundary>administrative</boundary>
<name>Quartier du Palais Royal</name>
<ref_INSEE>7510103</ref_INSEE>
<short_name>Palais Royal</short_name>
<source>www.mairie1.paris.fr</source>
<type>boundary</type>
<wikidata>Q1763626</wikidata>
<wikipedia>fr:Quartier du Palais-Royal</wikipedia>
</admin10>
</adminareas>
<major>
<latt>48.85341</latt>
<longt>2.3488</longt>
<elevation>42</elevation>
<timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
<city>Paris</city>
<name>Paris</name>
<prov>Île-de-France</prov>
<region>Paris</region>
<state>FR</state>
<inlatt>48.866667</inlatt>
<inlongt>2.333333</inlongt>
<distance>1.858</distance>
</major>
<geocode>PARIS-AZLQK</geocode>
<geonumber>3156715711198</geonumber>
<threegeonames>PARIS-DEKHA-BESTELLEN</threegeonames>
</geodata>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Google's Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#optional_parameters

You can pass `result_type` in the query string to filter by country, states, city, other administrative levels, including park and street. See the different `result_types` in documentation Example:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452 &location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

In your [response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#reverse-example) JSON, inside `address_components` field, you can view the results and filter it further for something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required Parameters.
latlng: Think of this as your secret code to tell the map where you are. It's like giving it the exact GPS numbers (latitude and longitude) of your location.
key: This is like your map pass. It's a special key that tells the map it's you asking for this information. It helps keep track of how much you use the map service. You can learn how to get this key in the instructions.

This is from API documentation of Google

```js
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
  ... Additional <code>results[]</code>
```